# Swift issue working with complex Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a complex dictionary which would hold the following data:

```
let teamInfo = [teamId : [teamInit, teamLogo]]
let gameInfo = [gameId : [gameStatus : status]]
                
let temp = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: teamInfo)
temp.addEntries(from: gameInfo)
                
complexDictionary[weekId] = temp
```

I am trying to declare my complexDictionary as such but has issues:

```
var complexDictionary = [String : [String : [String : String]], [String : [Bool : Bool]]] ()
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on  your "issues"?  But, really, you should not be using `NSMutableDictionary` In Swift. You also probably should not be using dictionaries of dictionaries. You should use structs. What is the point of a `[Bool:Bool]`?

Comment: @Paulw11 You are likely correct, im still learning the ropes sort of speak. Can you clarify what you mean by using structs instead?

Comment: wasn't too hard to google: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: indeed structs are probably better in the long run, but knowing how to use Swift `Dictionary` (aka `[AnyHashable: Any]` might be a beneficial first step https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var complexDictionary = [String : [String : [String : String]], [String : [Bool : Bool]]] ()
```

cause :

> Expected ':' in dictionary literal

because you are adding a `,` between `[String : [String : [String : String]]]` which is a valid dictionary type and `[String : [Bool : Bool]]` which is another (and I guess you wanted `[String : [String : [Bool : Bool]]]`)
what you need here is `[String: Any]`:

```
let teamInfo = ["teamId" : ["teamInit", "teamLogo"]]
let gameInfo = ["gameId" : [true : false]]

let temp = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: teamInfo)
temp.addEntries(from: gameInfo)
                
var complexDictionary: [String : Any] = [:]

complexDictionary["weekId"] = temp // ["teamId": ["teamInit", "teamLogo"], "gameId": [1: 0]]
```